# Passing BYTE arguments to a procedure using INVOKE MASM

Tags: assembly, parameters, invoke, masm32, irvine32

So I am trying to have a user enter in a string and I need to keep count of how many occurrences of letters are in the users string. Ex. "Hello" H = 1, e = 1, l =2, so on.

However, I am having trouble passing a pointer of size BYTE and the length of the string which is max 132 characters to my procedure called GetNumLetters.

When I get the length of the string for example "Hello" the stringLength = 5 but when I pass stringLength to my procedure the parameter that stores that value (arrayLength) is not equal to 5 but is like some crazy number 8398473. I just don't understand why arrayLength is not equal 5 when I pass stringLength to the function GetNumLetters. (I haven't tested the rest of the function since I can't get the size of the string).

My thinking is that stringLength is passing 8 bits and the 24 other bits are being randomly padded. However, I don't know how I would fill type cast stringLength to be 32 bits with the upper 24 bits = 0 in this case.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

INCLUDE Macros.inc

GetNumLetters PROTO, arrayInput: PTR BYTE, arrayCount: PTR BYTE, arrayLength: BYTE  
PrintNumLetters PROTO, arrayCount: PTR BYTE, arrayLength: BYTE

.data

charInput BYTE 132 DUP (?) ;an array that stores the users input of 132 values

charCount BYTE 123 DUP (0)      ;an array to store the instances of letters ONLY CARE ABOUT ASCII CHAR A-Z,a-z,0-9

stringLength BYTE 0             ;length of the string

msg BYTE "Enter String: ",0


.code
main proc

    xor edx, edx
    xor eax, eax
    xor ecx, ecx
    mov edx, OFFSET msg
    Call WriteString
    mov edx, OFFSET charInput   ;point to buffer you want input stored
    mov ecx, SIZEOF charInput   ;specify length of string
    call ReadString             ;get string from user
    mov stringLength, BYTE PTR eax   ;make 32bit to 8bit


    INVOKE GetNumLetters, OFFSET charInput, OFFSET charCount, stringLength  

    exit
main ENDP

;==========================================================================

GetNumLetters PROC, arrayInput: PTR BYTE, arrayCount: PTR BYTE, arrayLength: BYTE
    ;might need to put arrayInput and arrayCount into esi edi
    push ecx
    push eax
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor eax, eax
    movzx ecx, arrayLength 

    movzx eax, arrayLength
    call WriteDec

    ;check for letters 0-9
    LoopG1:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR [arrayInput + ecx]
            dec ecx                         ;decrease loop counter
            cmp eax, 48                     ;check if eax < 0
            jb LoopG1                       ; if eax < 0 try another letter
            cmp eax, 57                     ;check if eax > 9
            ja LoopG1                       ; if eax > 9 try another letter
            inc DWORD PTR [arrayCount + eax]            ;increment the letter's count
            jmp LoopG1

    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR arrayLength
    ;check for letters A-Z
    LoopG2:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR [arrayInput + ecx]
            dec ecx                         ;decrease loop counter
            cmp eax, 65                     ;check if eax is < A
            jb LoopG2                       ; if eax < A try another letter
            cmp eax, 90                     ;else check if eax > Z
            ja LoopG2                       ; if eax > Z try another letter
            inc DWORD PTR [arrayCount + eax]            ;increment the letter's count
            jmp LoopG2

    xor ecx, ecx
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR arrayLength
    ;check for letters a-z
    LoopG3:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR [arrayInput + ecx]
            dec ecx                         ;decrease loop counter
            cmp eax, 97                     ;check if eax is < a
            jb LoopG3                       ; if eax < a try another letter
            cmp eax, 122                    ;else check if eax > z
            ja LoopG3                       ; if eax > z try another letter
            inc DWORD PTR [arrayCount + eax]            ;incrememnt the letter's count
            jmp LoopG3
    pop ebp
    pop eax
    pop ecx
    ret 12      ;return 12 bytes to esp for the 3 parameters (take up 4 bytes each)
                ; even though they are BYTE
GetNumLetters ENDP
```

Comment: Why don't you use a disassembler to see what MASM did for the `INVOKE GetNumLetters, OFFSET charInput, OFFSET charCount, stringLength` line?   Most debuggers should have a disassembler built-in, and it sounds like you are using a debugger already.  But anyway, you don't need to use these pseudo-instructions and could just write your own PUSH and CALL instructions.  (Note that there is no `PUSH r/m8`, so most likely it pushing garbage, and your function is apparently not ignoring it.  Also note that you could just define `stringLength` as an EQU constant anyway, instead of loading it from mem).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a disassembler to see what MASM did for the `INVOKE GetNumLetters, OFFSET charInput, OFFSET charCount, stringLength` line?   Most debuggers should have a disassembler built-in, and it sounds like you are using a debugger already.

But anyway, you don't need to use these pseudo-instructions and could just write your own PUSH and CALL instructions.

**[Note that there is no `PUSH r/m8`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html), so most likely it pushing garbage along with your byte**, and your function is apparently not ignoring it.

Also note that you could just define `stringLength` as an EQU constant anyway, instead of loading it from mem.

---

You're probably also breaking MASM's attempts to help you by doing other pushes before `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp`.  I don't know MASM, but I assume that `GetNumLetters PROC, arrayInput: PTR BYTE, arrayCount: PTR BYTE, arrayLength: BYTE` generates some prologue for you, or defines those names as an offset from EBP that assumes you set up your stack frame first thing on function entry.

Again, look at actual disassembly with numeric offsets to see what really happened.

Note that the usual calling convention is for EAX, ECX, and EDX to be call-clobbered, so you should write functions to assume that any functions they call will clobber those regs, and in your own functions don't waste instructions saving/restoring them.  i.e. remove the `push ecx` and `push eax` entirely, instead of moving them after the `push ebp`.